# How to make <svg> always fit an image

Tags: html, css, svg, frontend

(Edited)
I am trying to make a webpage that displays an image that should either fill 50% of the width, or 80% of the height of the page, depending on the aspect ratio. I want to always display the full image without any distortions, and I need the surrounding svg to be the same size as the image inside. The webpage will allow users to draw on the image and save their changes. This must be dynamic, so that any image will work.

This is the code that I have right now. I expected it to scale the image to 50% of the page width without changing the aspect ratio, and expand the svg to fit around the image. However, the height of the svg does not match the height of the image.

html:

```
<svg id="svg">
    <image href="data:image/png;base64,{{ my_image }}"/>
</svg>
```

css:

```
#svg {
    width: 50%;
    height: fit-content;
}

#svg image {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

After I get the height of the div to match the height of the image, how can I set a max-height without cutting off part of the image?

Comment: What's `image` tag? Maybe `img`? And `my-div` this is class.

Comment: ```<img``` and ```src``` not ```<image``` and ```href```.

Comment: The image tag is an SVG element. When the html is parsed, it is synonymous with the <img> tag.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image

Comment: "depending on the aspect ratio" how is aspect ratio calculated? What is the use of this parent div?

Comment: For my purposes, I think I need to use an svg, since I am allowing the user to draw on the image and want to save those changes. This means that I actually need an <svg> tag around the image. It looks something like this now:
<svg id="svg">
        <image href="data:image/png;base64,{{ encoded_image }}"/>   
</svg>

The issue is still the same though, even with the <div> swapped with the <svg> 
I was actually able to format things correctly if I changed it to a <div> and an <img> tag, but I don't think I will be able to rasterize if I do that...

Comment: I don't think you can use the ```<image>``` tag as a direct child of a ```<div>``` tag. It is part of ```svg```.

Comment: You updated your code, now you're targeting an ```id``` in your css, but you have set a ```class```.

Comment: @prettyInPink my bad! I meant to write id="svg"

Comment: How about this: https://jsfiddle.net/0d7yeqho/, does this help?

Comment: If I upload an image with a different size the bottom part gets cut off... Is there a way to do this to allow dynamically sized boxes? Ultimately the image will be whatever the user uploads.
I also made a jsfiddle that shows the more complete code:
https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=13p0cuowJG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can adjust the parent element according to the size of the child image element but you can set

```
overflow:auto;
display: table;
```

of the parent element to display the child image element properly.

CSS:

```
#svg {
    width: 50%;
    display: table;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: It's almost there! Now, the full image shows, the only issue is that the image will now overlap with other elements on the page. Adding a margin didn't prevent items from overlapping. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Is it possible that you can use <div> tag instead of <svg> tag. Then the job would be easier.

Comment: No, but I did just realize that the overlapping issue came from the styling of one of my buttons... So this solution is actually totally valid!